# Order of accuracy and big-oh for $f_i '' \approx \frac{1}{h}^2 \Delta^2 f_i$

Tags: numerical-methods

I know that $\Delta^2 f_i = f_{i+2} - 2 f_{i+1} + f_i$, but I've got no idea how to find its order of accuracy and big-oh! Any slight hint might be helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Slight hint**. Expand right side in Taylor series around $x = x_i$. The difference between the left side and the right side would be the truncation error you're looking for.

> The order is first.